# Dynamically creating multiple form group using reactive forms in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, dynamic-forms

I want to create multiple form group.

When we need 3 form group that time we are declare multiple form using these way

```
form1: new FormGroup({
    firstName1: new FormControl(''),
    lastName1: new FormControl(''),
  });
form2: new FormGroup({
    firstName2: new FormControl(''),
    lastName2: new FormControl(''),
  });
form3: new FormGroup({
    firstName3: new FormControl(''),
    lastName3: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

these form group we are declare as a static and then used it in form.

I want to create form group and its form control dynamically using JSON file
JSON file format and create those HTML forms.

```
forms : [
  {
    type: 'form',
    objectName: 'form1',
    fields:[
        {
         name: 'firstName1'
        },
        {
         name: 'lastName1'
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'form',
    objectName: 'form2',
    fields:[
        {
         name: 'firstName1'
        },
        {
         name: 'lastName1'
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

how i can create multiple form groups dynamically?

Comment: Hi Arikael, I want to create dynamically multiple forms for validation

Comment: a quick google search reveals a lot of links for that topic.
e.g. -> https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-dynamic-components-forms
which seems what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for quick response Arikael, I have already check these links they have just create dynamically form control properties, they are declare as a static form objects

Comment: Hi Arikael, I just want suppose i have to need create 4 html forms with validation in angular. but i don`t want to declare as a static form i want create these form as dynamically.

Comment: have you looked at my link?
It looks very dynamic, look at how it's used

`<div class="app">
      <dynamic-form 
        [config]="config"
        (submitted)="formSubmitted($event)">
      </dynamic-form>
    </div>`

what doesn't fit your need?

Comment: here they have declare `<form class="dynamic-form" [formGroup]="form"></form>` the `formGroup` object is define. i want to create multiple form group dynamically as `<form class="dynamic-form" [formGroup]="form1"></form>` `<form class="dynamic-form" [formGroup]="form2"></form>` `<form class="dynamic-form" [formGroup]="form3"></form>` i want create `form1, form2, form3` objects dynamically

Comment: you could create them in a loop. I think the linked post is a great starting point and will get you very far (I'd say it gets to to the your goal)

Comment: You can refer this http://keepnote.cc/code/form-group-with-formarray-adding-dyamic-row-angular-5-6

Comment: its not fit on my requirements. thanks for try

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: the same requirement i also have. in my case,  the issue is that I have huge HTML content in JSON representation, and the form could be anywhere on any node of the tree and any number of times, to build the elements am using renderer2, so am planning to have a separate element handler if <form> tag is there and I want to create the form dynamically in that handler. if you guys have any solution please write and answer.